# how to trigger an href and php code with single onclick event of submit button

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've seen many forums, but couldn't figure this out. Please help and guide.
When I click the submit button, I am taken to a href file location ... no problem with this. Simultaneously I want to add details of the event to a table named 'docdownloads'. My code looks like this. Currently my table is getting updated without clicking the submit button. I want both the events to occur together and be triggered by the single click.

```
<?php
echo "<input type='submit' value='Click Here To Download' ". $downloaddisabled."      onclick='window.location.href=\"$docpath\"'>";
echo '<br>';


if ($downloaddisabled!="disabled" ) {
$sql4="INSERT INTO docdownloads (accno, username, userid, downloadtime, filename) VALUES('$accno', '$uname', '$uid', '$downloadtime', '$docpath')";
if (!mysqli_query($con1, $sql4)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con1));
    }
echo "one record added";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Way I do things.
Create a seprate page for recording things in MySQL and when your things are done redirect it to downloadable item.

Original Page:

```
<?

echo "<input type='submit' value='Click Here To Download' ". 
             $downloaddisabled."
             onclick='window.location.href=\"$docpath_special_Page\"'>";
echo '<br>';

?>
```

docpath_special_Page:

```
<?php
   $sql4="INSERT INTO docdownloads (accno, username, userid, downloadtime, 
          filename) VALUES('$accno', '$uname', '$uid', '$downloadtime', 
          '$docpath')";
    if (!mysqli_query($con1, $sql4)) {
          die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con1));
     }
     header("Location:/".$docpath);
     exit(0);

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestions, I'll try them out. But really I want to avoid going to another page. Some more ideas please.

Comment: made some minor changes, added joomla header info, viola it worked. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to have three pages

Page one: contains the submit button (with link to page 2). Also, make the $downloaddisabled a session variable so that it can be accessed on other pages

Page two: Checkes the session variable for being equal to disabled, if yes.. executes SQL.
This page also redirects to the third page automatically

Page three: Your final destination

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue am not sure how exactly is to mine but I had to submit form details to PayPal , save the same detail to database and send email of the details...

This is what you have to do:

1. Create form that will send details to database and you can put values hidden if you wish for normal user to see the details.

   `<form name="insert_to_table_docdownloads" method="post" id="msend"     action="insert.php" target="_main">
    <input type="hidden" name="accno" value=""> 
    <input type="hidden" name="username" value=""> 
    </form>`

were insert.php contain sql insert command

2. Create another form which will view details you want to see

   `<form name="download" id="download" >
    <input type="text" value="">
    </form>`
3. Then create JavaScript button to submit both form by id

   `<input type="image" src="button_img.png" onclick="document.getElementById ('msend').submit();document.getElementById('download').submit();" />`

Tell me if it works for you.